# Is it bad practice to use PHP Print to show jQuery Function?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Need to show a certain piece of jQuery in the header of a wordpress site for settings of a plugin. Is it bad practice to use this the php print method to accomplish it? I'm using the following code:

```
<?php is_page( 'front-page' ); print 
"<script>
jQuery(function() {

        jQuery('#bannerscollection_kenburns_majestic').bannerscollection_kenburns({
            skin: 'majestic',
            width: 2530,
            height: 1200,
            autoHideNavArrows:true,
            numberOfThumbsPerScreen:16,
            thumbsOnMarginTop:23,
            thumbsWrapperMarginTop: 0,
            initialZoom: 1,
            finalZoom: 1,       
        });     


    });
</script>"
?>
```

EDIT

I ended up using this, which works great.

```
<?php is_page( 'front-page' ); wp_enqueue_script( 'kbsettings' ); ?>
```

Comment: better

`<?php is_page( 'front-page' ); echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='js/myplugin.js'></script>'"; ?>`

Comment: Personally, I consider any echo/print which is outputting a multi-line string to be bad practice, especially when there's embedded quotes. [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc)s exist for exactly this situation. And for unchanging fixed text like this, breaking out of PHP mode (`?>`) is even better.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can try like this

```
<?php if(is_page( 'front-page' )){ ?>
<script>
jQuery(function() {

        jQuery('#bannerscollection_kenburns_majestic').bannerscollection_kenburns({
            skin: 'majestic',
            width: 2530,
            height: 1200,
            autoHideNavArrows:true,
            numberOfThumbsPerScreen:16,
            thumbsOnMarginTop:23,
            thumbsWrapperMarginTop: 0,
            initialZoom: 1,
            finalZoom: 1,       
        });     


    });
</script>



<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but doing it this way has never worked for me in a wordpress template. Not sure why.

Comment: Then try `echo` as the comment by @eicto

Comment: You might find the alternative control structure syntax more readable if doing this: `<?php if (foo()): ?> ... <?php endif ?>` http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: Check my edit. I think that might be the best, wordpress friendly way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally yes, it is bad practice to generate static content in dynamic script, it affects service performance (standalone js cached in user's browser and php interpreter have to process your lines again and again)

use something like that  :

```
<?php
echo is_page( 'front-page' ) 
        ? "<script type='text/javascript' src='js/myplugin.js'></script>'" 
        : ""; 
?>
```

Also, may  be you install your plugin in wordpress template of front page ?

Comment: There is a much worse issue than performance: Lack of syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really be printing that many lines. As mentioned, you could use a HEREDOC? Usually, JS in PHP is really only if you need PHP variables in your JS. I don't see that here?

Why can't you just load that script instead of printing it?

```
<?php if is_front_page(){ //the general best practice way of getting the front page
    include(YOURPATH.'js/yourfile.js');
?>
```